# Iterating over features in vector layer

Tags: pyqgis, iteration

Im trying to iterate over features in a vector layer following [Iterating over Vector Layer](http://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/pyqgis_developer_cookbook/vector.html#iterating-over-vector-layer):

```
from qgis.core import *
import qgis.utils
from qgis.core import QgsVectorLayer

shapefile = '/media/bera/Lagring/GIS/data/ok_riks_Sweref_99_TM_shape/oversikt/riks/ak_riks.shp'

layer = QgsVectorLayer(shapefile, 'borders', 'ogr')
it = layer.getFeatures()

for feature in it:
    geom = feature.geometry()
    print geom.type()
    print 'test'

print 'stop'
```

It will not go into the `for` block so all that is printed out is `stop`

The objects are created:

```
layer
<qgis._core.QgsVectorLayer object at 0x7fa08d2bcb98>
it
<qgis._core.QgsFeatureIterator object at 0x7fa08d32e218>
```

What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [Using PyQGIS in standalone scripts](http://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/pyqgis_developer_cookbook/intro.html#using-pyqgis-in-standalone-scripts) i added:

```
QgsApplication.setPrefixPath("/home/bera/.qgis2/", True) #Path to qgis installation
qgs = QgsApplication([], False)
qgs.initQgis()

#Script goes here

qgs.exitQgis()
```

And now it is working

Answer (score 5):

Check [that the layer is valid](http://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/pyqgis_developer_cookbook/loadlayer.html#vector-layers). If the layer, or the path is not valid qgis will no raise an error, it will return a `QgsVectorLayer` object where you can call the methods but with mostly no-op.

```
layer = QgsVectorLayer(shapefile, 'borders', 'ogr')
if not layer.isValid():
    raise Exception('Layer is not valid')
```

It will be probably a bad path. Also try to open (manually) the file in qgis to check if there is any error with the shp.

Comment: It was not valid